# How to reach Config Editor in Thunderbird on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

Your instructions "It Thunderbird go to Tools >> Options >> Advanced >> Config Editor

Then search for mail.identity.default.suppress_signature_separator and set it to TRUE by double-clicking it.

Now, you will no longer get the -- before the signature." do not appear to apply to my system where I am unable to find the menu items "tools/options/advanced" - I get "tools" then a long dropdown menu but no "options" in my Thunderbird 52.1.1 (64 bit)

Answer (score 0):

On my 52.1.1 on 16.04:

- Edit>Preferences
- "Advanced" tab
- "Config editor..." button (lower right)